# AWK print if found three matches, one false

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

There is several lines in a file that looks like:

```
A   B   C   H
A   B   C   D
```

and, I want to print all lines that contain this RE:

```
/A\tB/
```

But, if the line contain and `H` in the fourth field, do not print, the output would be:

```
A   B   C   D
```

**It could be written in one line in sed, awk or grep?**

The only thing that I know is:

```
awk '/^A\tB/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **awk** one-liner:

```
awk -F'\t' '$1=="A" && $2=="B" && $4!="H"' file
```

- `-F'\t'` - tab char `\t` is treated as field separator

The output:

```
A   B   C   D
```

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
awk '$1$2 == "AB" && $4 != "H"' file
```

If all entries are single characters this will also work:

```
awk '$1$2$3$4 ~ /^AB.[^H]/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed  '/^A\tB\t.\t[^H]/!d' file
```

If a line does not contain `A` ,`B` ,any character and a character other than `H` separated by tabs, delete it.

Could be written:

```
 sed  -n '/^A\tB\t.\t[^H]/p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
awk '/^A\tB/ { if ( $4 != "H" ) print }'
```

Comment: typo, `'` should be after last `}` ... can be simplified and made more robust matching for 2nd column `awk '/^A\tB\t/ &&  $4 != "H"'`

Comment: @Sundeep  Ok.Thanks